# Using Grunt to create file from other files

Tags: angularjs, gruntjs

Let's say I have the following file structure (in some sections of a project, but not others)

```
index.html
otherPage.html

/js
/css
/templates
  ** file1.html
  ** file2.html
```

I am using Angular and Require.JS for a project at work. I'm trying to use dynamic templates with Angular, and for the easiest solution I'm manually creating and editing a new file at the root directory, `templates.html` .

Is there a way for Grunt to automatically:

1. Look to see if /templates folder exists
2. Read through the .html files inside /templates and store the content of each file in an array
3. Create `Templates.html`
4. Insert the contents of the templates array with each template wrapped with `<script id="filename.html"></script>`

Just trying to figure out what is possible with `grunt.file.read` and `grunt.file.write`.. The documentation doesn't provide much in terms of examples.

Thanks!

Comment: You can also use the [`grunt-shell`](https://github.com/sindresorhus/grunt-shell) plugin for arbitrary shell/bash commands.

Comment: Were you able to figure this out. ?

Comment: My idea at the time got shot down, so I never looked into it further. For what it's worth I'm at a company that uses Gulp now, and it's much easier to work with in general.